# Could applying assimilation affect meaning?

Tags: prefix, phonology, consonants

The two grammatical terms "adposition" and "apposition" are related to [*adpositiō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adpositio#Latin), which has an alternative form *appositiō*. In *appositiō* assimilation applied, while in *adpositiō* assimilation does not occur.
Could applying optional assimilation affect the meaning of a word in Latin?

Comment: Do you mean in the short term or in the long term? Assimilation is just a change in pronunciation that gets reflected in writing. But in the long term an old writing/pronunciation can be _reacquired_ as a cultism with a different meaning. (Either more specialized, closer to the original, if the meaning has changed, or both.)

Comment: Good question. In my experience, it does not affect semantics. But, who knows, perhaps an exception can be found!

Comment: In esssence, you are asking whether two different words derived from the same source can have different meaning; to which the answer is a resounding Yes!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a partial answer, since the question has sat unanswered for months.

I don't know of any examples of this kind of optional assimilation between the last consonant in a prefix and the first consonant of the base making a difference in the meaning of a word in Latin. Cerberus also left a comment saying

> In my experience, it does not affect semantics. But, who knows, perhaps an exception can be found!